# Get nickname of disconnected client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

In my socket.io chat application, I am trying to get the nickname of the clientwho just disconnected.

I did:

```
client.on('disconnect', function(nickname){
    console.log(nickname + " has disconnected.");
    client.get('nickname', function(error, nickname){
        client.broadcast.emit("remove chatter", nickname);

        redisClient.srem("chatters", nickname);
    });
});
```

But I am getting the following:

```
transport close has disconnected.

TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'get'
```

I googled but didnt find anything reliable.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.nickname` solved the problem.